two equivalent definitions of deformation of a subscheme
I am reading a very beginning of a short note on deformations: https://raymondvanbommel.nl/2015/Mg3_Pagano.pdf by Pagano. The setup is as follows: say one has a $k-$scheme $X=Spec(B)$ and a closed subscheme $Spec(B/I)=Y\subset X$. Denote $B'= B\otimes k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$.
Then a deformation of $Y$ in $X$ is a data of
an ideal $I'\subset B'$ such that

$B'/I'$ is a flat $k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)-$module
$B'/I'\otimes_{k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)}k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon)=B/I$.

I want to see that giving a deformation in the above sense is equivalent to giving a section of a normal bundle of $Y$ in $X$; dual of such a section is a map $I/I^2\to B/I$ (geometrically giving a section of normal bundle is very reasonable to me). In line 12 on page 1 Pagano writes that a choice of such an ideal $I'$ is equivalent to a choice of a normal section. I am unable to see this formally, could you help me write down how to get a section out of such ideal $I'$?

This is essentially the content of section 1.2 of Hartshorne's Deformation Theory.
